# SSRS Expression issues

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to write an expression in SSRS but I keep getting the error message below:

> "Textbox1 uses a first, last or previous aggregate in an outer
>   aggregate. These Aggregate functions cannot be specified as nested
>   aggregates"

What does this mean?

All I'm trying to do is to write an expression that will:

count the number of cards where the activation date <=period_start_date AND (Deactivation date is null OR Deactivation Date >=period_start_date)

This is how my expression looks:

```
=Count(
        IIF(
            (First(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_activate_DT_SHORT.Value, "DataSet1")<=First(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Period_Start_DT_SHORT.Value, "DataSet1"))
            AND
            ( 
              First(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value, "DataSet1")=""
              OR
              (First(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value, "DataSet1")>=First(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Period_Start_DT_SHORT.Value, "DataSet1"))
            )
  ,Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Unit_ID.Value
  ,0
  )
)
```

Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see code below:
let me know if it works or what is the error message:

```
=Count(
        IIF(
            ((Fields!CUBD_CareDay_activate_DT_SHORT.Value)<=Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Period_Start_DT_SHORT.Value))
            AND
            ( 
              (Fields!CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value)=""
              OR
              ((Fields!CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value)>=(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Period_Start_DT_SHORT.Value))
            )   ,Fields!CUBD_CareDay_Unit_ID.Value   ,0   ) )
```

Comment: I get a The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox162.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid

Comment: Instead of CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value)="" I tried IsNothing(Fields!CUBD_CareDay_deactivate_DT_SHORT.Value) and it seems is getting the right result